# Prevent UISearchBar from indenting right when tapped

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

In my `viewDidLoad`, I programmatically create a search bar.  When the search field is tapped, the search bar indents to the right.  Why is this happening and how do I prevent it from doing so?  I am not using autolayout.

```
- (void)createSearchBar {
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's also moving upwards?

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the `positionAdjustmentForSearchBarIcon:` or `setPositionAdjustment:forSearchBarIcon:`
message calls to the searchbar inside the delegate call:`searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:`

Comment: That didn't work.   I am able to set the frame's x origin to 0 in searchBarShouldBeginEditing but then the search bar becomes the full width of the screen when it needs to be to the right of the button (in the screenshot above).  I also can't seem to change the search bar's height.